# Exception in ESAPI.clearCurrent(); Dont know what ESAPI.Logger use

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, esapi

Trying to use **ESAPI validation** in our Java web Application, we get the next exception:

```
org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Authenticator class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.FileBasedAuthenticator) CTOR threw exception.
    at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:129)    
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.authenticator(ESAPI.java:92)   
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.clearCurrent(ESAPI.java:61)    
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.owasp.esapi.logging.log4j.Log4JLogFactory
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:74)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.logFactory(ESAPI.java:137)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.getLogger(ESAPI.java:154)
```

We use:

**esapi-2.2.3.0.jar**

**log4j-1.2-api-2.12.4.jar**

**log4j-api-2.12.4.jar**

**log4j-core-2.12.4.jar**

and this definition in the **ESAPI.properties**:

```
ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.log4j.Log4JLogFactory
```

Other definitions also doesn't works:

```
#ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLogFactory
```

Answer (score 1):

With this works:

```
ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaLogFactory
```

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, the answer provided by JLLMNCHR is in fact, the correct one.

Here are some more important missing details...  Changes to the fully qualified class names for the **ESAPI.Logger** property in your **ESAPI.properties** file and other related changes were first mentioned in the ESAPI 2.2.1.0 release notes (when support for SLF4J was first added) in https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/documentation/esapi4java-core-2.2.1.0-release-notes.txt#L128-L155 where these changes were first mentioned, and thereafter in several successive release notes up through ESAPI release 2.3.0.0. It was also announced on the ESAPI-Project-Users Google group that is mentioned in our README file as well as ESAPI's pom.xml.

Also, seeing that you are still using the Log4J 1 logger, I want to call your attention to this important announcement regarding that. Support for Log4J 1 (unless you want to use it via an SLF4J bridge) will be going away, probably in the next release, which we are planning sometime next month. For details, see https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/discussions/711.